# In BeautifulSoup, how do I search for an element within another element?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using Django 2, Python 3.7, and BeautifulSoup 4.  I have the below code, which is supposed to find an element within an element ...

```
req = urllib2.Request(fullurl, headers=settings.HDR)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=settings.SOCKET_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS).read()
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
pattern = re.compile(r'^submitted ')
posted_elt = bs.find(text=pattern)
author_elt = posted_elt.find("span", class_="author") if posted_elt is not None else None
```

However the line

```
author_elt = posted_elt.find("span", class_="author") if posted_elt is not None else None
```

is throwing the error "TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments".  What's the correct way to search for an element within another element?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: If you check `type(posted_elt)` it will be some string type, not an element. You've selected the text inside a node. The `find` is `str.find`. Not sure how to do this selection...

Comment: `find(text=pattern)` gives `bs4.element.NavigableString` which is string

Comment: @furas - true in general but in this case OP shows the line and the error. Seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: @tdelaney it gives the same - bs4.element.NavigableString is string so OP runs `string.find()` in next line

Comment: You would use `find(tag, text=pattern)` to get it as BS element which can use `.find("span", class_="author")`

Comment: @furas, I think that OP wants to find `<span>` elements below whatever element has the text he is looking for. In XPATH I think it would be something like `".//*[starts-with(text(), 'submitted ')]/span[@class='author']"` but I haven't tested that.

Comment: Please share some example input and output.

Comment: @tdelaney your xpath seems OK but as I know BeautifulSoup doesn't have function to use xpath - even if BS uses `lxml` :(  OP would have to use direcetly `lxml`

Comment: @furas - yeah, I think that if you import `lxml` and then use its beautifulsoup, you get xpath. But I don't quite remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search for text in BeautifulSoup, you get a `bs4.element.NavigableString` object that is much like a regular python `str`. Luckily, it has that "Navigable" part in it. `navigableString.parent` references the parent element which can be used in the next find. You aren't trying to find a `<span>` child of the text node because text nodes don't have child elements. You are trying to find the element that has this text node, and continuing the search from there.

```
req = urllib2.Request(fullurl, headers=settings.HDR)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=settings.SOCKET_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS).read()
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
pattern = re.compile(r'^submitted ')
posted_elt = bs.find(text=pattern)
author_elt = posted_elt.parent.find("span", class_="author") if posted_elt is not None else None
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.find()` method searches for html tags. When the tag is found you should convert the result to string using the `.text` attribute of `.find()` results. Then use your regex search on that string.

Here is example usage:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"html.parser")
reg = re.compile("-")
s = soup.find("title").text
print(re.search(reg,s).group(0))

# If you want to find all html tags and search each of them use find_all()

all_res = soup.find_all("p")
reg = re.compile("dog")
for i in all_res:
    s = i.text
    match = re.search(reg,s)
    if match:
        print(match.group(0))
```

The later example will find all `<p>` tags convert them to string and search for "dog" in them.